# zsh heroku and Env Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, mailer

I have no idea why I'm not able to set my gmail env variable on my heroku server. I ran and set the User name easily according [to their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application), by running

```
heroku config:add GMAIL_USERNAME=usersname@gmail.com
```

But, now when I try to setup the password to go along with this for my use in the mailer

```
heroku config:add GMAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

I'm getting the error

```
zsh: no matches found: GMAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

I have no idea why I'm not able to set this variable in this way much less why I'm getting this output from my shell.

A few things about this part of my setup.

-using `loca_env.yml` for mailer username and password, that is checked into `.gitignore` (hence setting this on heroku servers.)

The mailer initializer-

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => "587",
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "myapp.herokuapp.com"
```

It mails fine in local and now I'm trying to test in a production setting without checking in `local_env.yml` into version control. Something simple I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can almost always coax your shell into handling special characters differently. For zsh, try this: `heroku config:add X='erwrewr#'`  The single quotes will ensure most special characters are suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

Something I hadn't considered until messing with it for another 30 min.

My actual password ended in a '#' which was causing my shell error. For anyone finding themselves in this edge case..Not sure what the special characters that won't allow you to set in different shell but something to check if you run across a similar error.